# How to optimize nested for loop

Tags: java

Suppose for Array `A` of length `L` and skip `value = k`
I have to find highest possible sum in an array for a given start point.
sum should be in such a way that the initial point taken in array should be added then the next point after initial `point+k` skip and so on

so what is the highest possible sum?

for example array `a=[1,9,2]` `k=2`

then highest possible sum would be 9

i used two for loops

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=i;j<a.length){
        sum+=a[j];
        j+=k;
    }
    if(sum>max)
        max=sum;

    sum=0;
}
```

Though this works its complexity would be `O(n^2)`;
how can reduce it?

Comment: Why are you incrementing `j` by `k+1` (in two separate operations)? Do you mean to do that?

Comment: Are the elements in the array non-negative, or can they be negative? If the former, you can change your outer loop guard to `i < k`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes elements can be negative also

Comment: @AndyTurner i mistyped and incremented j by k + 1; i have edited it now

Comment: now your code is invalid: it should be `for(int j=i;j<a.length;){` (extra semicolon); but it would be neater just to put the `j+=k` in the loop declaration (and remove fr body): `for(int j=i;j<a.length; j+=k){`